# What is the rule of $1.96$ for estimating confidence intervals?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I have a sequence of A/B currency exchanges for some days. With that data I can calculate the daily returns, and that's what I did. I need to calculate the confidence interval for the expected daily returns of the A/B currency exchange by using the $1.96$ rule.

What is this $1.96$ rule? Why exactly that number? Why is it related to compute confidence intervals? So, how can we use it in general to compute confidence intervals?

There's an article on Wikipedia, but honestly I am not understanding it, and why it is related to the calculation of the confidence interval of the expectation.

Note that for now I am not asking specifically about how to solve my problem, but how what I am asking about is related to my problem (after answering those questions).

Comment: Probability a normal lies within $1.96$ standard deviations from the mean is $95\%$. A choice of $95\%$ is somewhat arbitrary but it spread wide and became somewhat standard. It's better to remember $68-95-99.7$ percent rule - that is probabilities to lie within $1-2-3$ standard deviations from the mean // What do you mean "why"? It's a property of a normal based on a numerical calculation.

Comment: Because when you average a lot of data points that come from a distribution with finite variance, distribution of this average will be approximately normal centered around the real mean. So the real mean will be within $1.96$ standard deviations from the estimated mean with probability $\approx 5\%$. This is assuming you know the real variance. If you estimate it from the sample, the answer changes a little bit but not significantly.

Answer (score 3):

**Normal condifidence interval.** If the data are normal with unknown population mean $\mu$ and known population standard deviation $\sigma$, then a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of random observations from the population and $\bar X$ is their mean.

In these circumstances, the quantity $Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ has a standard normal distribution so that
$P(-1.96 < Z < 1.96) = 0.95.$ After some algebra we have
$$P(\bar X - 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n} < \mu < \bar X + 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n})
= 0.95.$$
Providing some detail behind the comments of @A.S., this relationship is the theoretical basis for the 95% confidence interval, according to the '1.96 rule'.

**$T$ confidence interval.** If $\sigma$ is unknown, then it may be estimated by the sample
standard deviation $S = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$ Then $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ has Student's t distribution with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom.

In that case 1.96 is replaced by the quantile .975 of Student's t distribution with degrees of freedom $n - 1.$ (Consult a printed
table or use statistical software.) For example, if there
are $n = 25$ observations, then 1.96 is replaced by 2.064. Then
the 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 2.064 S/\sqrt{n}.$

The quantity $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is called the 'standard error' of the mean and $S/\sqrt{n}$ is the '(estimated) standard error'. Roughly
speaking, one says that a 95% CI for $\mu$ is the sample mean
plus or minus two standard errors. Notice that 1.96 and 2.064 are both very nearly 2. (This is approximately right
unless $n$ is much smaller than 30.)

Here is a numerical example. Suppose you have the following
25 random observations from a normal population with both
$\mu$ and $\sigma$ unknown:

```
 108.813  58.390  68.755  81.158 103.187  69.462 100.649 122.459 110.655 105.205
 104.437 113.235  90.729 121.323  99.589 110.171 100.048 120.692  91.874  67.900
 115.998 117.684  86.843  92.896 114.018
```

Then $\bar X = 99.0468,\,$ $S = 18.32374,\,$ $S/\sqrt{n} =  3.097277,\,$ and (rounded to two places) a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is
$(91.48,  106.61).$  These calculations were done in R statistical
software, as shown below.

```
 mean(x);  sd(x);  qt(.975, 24)
 ## 99.0468
 ## 18.32374
 ## 2.063899
 mean(x) + c(-1,1)*qt(.975, 24)*sd(x)/sqrt(25)
 ##  91.48313 106.61047
```

*References:* The NIST Engineering Statistics Handbook (available online) has more
information at a basic level and also tables of normal and t
distributions. Perhaps begin with sections 1.3.5.2 and 7.2.2.1.

*Notes:* I am not familiar with the kind of currency exchange data
you are using, so I do not know whether the data are normal. If they are far from normal, the confidence intervals described here may not be appropriate. Other options are available, but I hope this
answer discusses CIs related to the '1.96 rule' in sufficient detail.

Comment: By the central limit theorem, you don't even need to assume normal random variables; you only need finite variance.

Comment: @M Turgeon: True enough if n is large enough for the CLT to be useful. In a practical situation of importance, I wouldn't want to use these CIs for exponential data with n = 25. Especially so, because a gamma-based CI is exact.

Comment: Fair enough. I forgot to mention that it would only be an approximation. And as you point out, it can be a poor one. Another example is binomial data with probability of success very close to zero or one.

Comment: Missing TeX code for the square root added. Sorry for the confusion. The sample standard deviation $S$ is often used to estimate $\sigma.$ The number 1.96 is found from a table of the normal distribution and the number 2.064 is found from a table of Student's t distribution. These numbers cut 2.5% from the upper tail of their respective distributions. Also, by symmetry, -1.96 and -2.064 cut 2.5% from the lower tails of the respective distributions. This leaves 95% in the central part of each distribution as req'd for the CI. You can see standard formulas and tables in a basic statistics text.

Comment: The validity of a CI based on a probability factor of 1.96 depends on the number of observations used to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and (especially for small $n$) on the distribution of the population.You are wise (a) to  have doubts and (b) not to get into an acrimonious debate with your professor.If this kind of inference becomes central to a project that is important to your career, then you can resurrect your doubts and learn more. It is not feasible to tell 'the whole truth' in an answer to one question, especially without full background info. One can try for 'nothing but the truth'.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $1.96$ stems from the fact that we generally use 5% significance level in computing the confidence interval or any hypothesis testing.

When we are looking for a two sided confidence interval of mean, we want to find the a value less than the sample mean, let it be $LL$ and another value above the sample mean, let's call it $UL$. Now these values are chosen in a manner that when sampled large number of times, the true mean will lie between these values 95% of the time.

Mathematically, $P(LL \leq \mu \leq UL) = 0.95$

Now suppose sample mean, $\bar{X} = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$ (That is sampling from N(0,1)). In this case if we want to estimate the true mean $\mu$, what should our $UL$ and $LL$ be?

By using the normal tables, we can see that $P(z \leq 1.96) = 0.975$ and $P(z \leq -1.96) = 0.025$.
Thus, $P(-1.96 \leq \mu \leq 1.96) = 0.95$

Similarly, for non standard cases,
${P(-1.96 \leq \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} \leq 1.96) = 0.95}.$

Or, ${P(\bar{X}-1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq \bar{X}+1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) = 0.95}.$

Thus, we write the confidence interval as $\bar{X} \pm 1.96 \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$

This value would be different if we need confidence interval at some other significance levels. For instance, for 99% confidence interval we shall use $2.576$